# Cannot update the nested Array of the boolean

Tags: javascript, mongodb, function, ecmascript-6, serverless

I am trying to update an array to show the router is up by using a true or false statement.

But I am getting a response back that "record is updated" but I am not able to see the change in MongoDB collection.

This is my function I am running

```
exports = async function({ body }) {
  const data = JSON.parse(body.text());
  const ACAS_Mission = data.ACAS_Mission;
  const terminal = data.terminals[0].terminal;
  const router = data.terminals[0].XLESS.router;

  const comstat = context.services
    .get("mongodb-atlas")
    .db("Comstat")
    .collection("comstat");

  // Find the document
  const filter = { ACAS_Mission, "terminals.terminal": terminal };
  const document = await comstat.findOne(filter);
  console.log("Document:", JSON.stringify(document));

  // Update the document
  const updateFilter = { ACAS_Mission, "terminals.terminal": terminal };
  const update = { $set: { "terminals.$[t].XLESS.router": router } };
  const options = { arrayFilters: [{ "t.terminal": terminal }] };
  const result = await comstat.updateOne(updateFilter, update, options);
  console.log("Update result:", JSON.stringify(result));

  return { message: "Record updated." };
};
```

and this is the document I am trying to update

[MongoDB Document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q1jh4.png)

The JSON Body that I am passing when I do a PUT

```
{
  "ACAS_Mission": "xx53583",
  "terminals": [
    {
      "terminal": "SNN573330",
      "XLESS": {
        "router": true
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: You are always returning `{message: "Record updated"}`. Just to be sure, are you really viewing the console output and not the message?

Comment: Update result: {"matchedCount":0,"modifiedCount":0}

So within my logs I am showing that it is wanting to do the PUT function but everything is matching based on my current document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you wrote in your comment, MongoDB processes the request, but there are no changes. That means that nothing in your datebase matched your query (as one may conclude from `matchedCount` being 0).

Check your query: Your screenshot shows that `terminals` contains an array containing another array containing an object. You are searching for an array directly containing an object, so adding [braces] around the statement might work.

Answer (score 0):

Was able to change the JSON body and a few function fixes and it works!

```
{
  "ACAS_Mission": "xx53583",
  "terminals": [
    [
      {
        "terminal": "SNN573330",
        "NodeID": 251,
        "XLESS": {
          "router": false
        }
      }
    ]
  ]
```